# REST Webservice @HttpGet

Tags: apex, webservices, rest

I am having trouble compiling a REST webservice class that I have created.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/LeadSAP/*')
global with sharing class SAPLeadWS
{

@HttpPost
global static String createNewLead(
                                    String firstName,
                                    String lastName,
                                    String title,
                                    String email,
                                    String workPhone,
                                    String mobilePhone,
                                    String comments,
                                    String street,
                                    String city,
                                    String state,
                                    String postalCode,
                                    String country
                                  )
{


Lead l = new Lead();
l.RecordTypeId = '01290000000hP9lAAE';
l.FirstName = firstName;
l.LastName = lastName;
l.title = title;
l.email = email;
l.Work_Phone__c = workPhone;
l.MobilePhone = mobilePhone;
l.Description = comments;
l.street = street;
l.city = city;
l.state = state;
l.postalCode = postalCode;
l.country = country;
insert l;

return l.Id;

}


@HttpGet
global static String getLead(String SAPId)
{

Lead l = [SELECT Id, FirstName,LastName,title,email,Work_Phone__c,MobilePhone,Description,street,city,state,postalcode,country from Lead WHERE Id = :SAPId ];
if(l == null)
{

return 'Lead Does Not Exist';

}
else
{

String s = 'Id = '+SAPid+' FirstName = '+l.FirstName+' LastName = '+l.LastName+' title = '+l.title+' email = '+l.email+' WorkPhone = '+l.Work_Phone__c+' MobilePhone = '+l.MobilePhone+' Description = '+l.description+' Street = '+l.street+' city = '+l.city+' state = '+l.state+' postalcode = '+l.postalcode+' country = '+l.country;
return s;

}

}

}
```

I was able to compile and test successfully the @HttpPost method but when I added the code for @HttpGet I am having compile errors.

The error says that

```
Error   Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: HTTP GET/DELETE methods do not support parameters at line 45 column 22
```

Without a parameter to pass I am not sure how @HttpGet can be built because my intention is to pass id and then return a string depending on whether there was a successful retrieval or not.

**UPDATED GET SECTION**

```
public static final String SAP_ID_PARAM = 'SAPId';


@HttpGet
global static String getLead()
{

//String jsonInstance = RESTContext.request.requestBody.toString();
//Payload p = JSON.deserialize(jsonInstance,Payload.class());

Id SAPId = RestContext.request.params.get(SAP_ID_PARAM);



Lead l = [SELECT Id, FirstName,LastName,title,email,Work_Phone__c,MobilePhone,Description,street,city,state,postalcode,country from Lead WHERE Id = :SAPId ];
if(l == null)
{

return 'Lead Does Not Exist';

}
else
{

String s = 'Id = '+SAPid+' FirstName = '+l.FirstName+' LastName = '+l.LastName+' title = '+l.title+' email = '+l.email+' WorkPhone = '+l.Work_Phone__c+' MobilePhone = '+l.MobilePhone+' Description = '+l.description+' Street = '+l.street+' city = '+l.city+' state = '+l.state+' postalcode = '+l.postalcode+' country = '+l.country;
return s;

}

}
```

Can someone tell me how to actually test this in Workbench as I am not sure how to send this parameter as part of restrequest ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use make use of the `RestContext.request`. The way you do so will vary based on the Http method in question.

**POST**

Here you will need to parse the `RestContext.request.requestBody`. Usually this will be a `JSON` payload which you `deserialize`. For example:

```
public class PostPayload
{
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String etc;
}

@HttpPost
global static void String createLead()
{
    String jsonInstance = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
    PostPayload payload = JSON.deserialize(jsonInstance), PostPayload.class);
    // do stuff
}
```

This payload can be set in your tests as follows:

```
MyRestService.PostPayload payload = new MyRestService.PostPayload;
payload.firstName = 'Road';
payload.lastName = 'Runner';
RestContext.request.requestBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(payload));
```

**GET**

Here you will need to pull values out of `RestContext.request.params`. I tend to make my keys constants so that I can test against them more easily.

```
public static final String SAP_ID_PARAM = 'sapId';

@HttpGet
global static void String getLead()
{
    Id sapId = RestContext.request.params.get(SAP_ID_PARAM);
    if (String.isBlank(sapId))
    {

    }
    // do stuff
}
```

This value can be set in your tests as follows:

```
RestContext.request.params.put(MyRestService.SAP_ID_PARAM, 'Some Value');
```

Comment: I don't think `GET` requests will have a `requestBody`.  Do they?

Comment: Hmm you're right. I think I'll need to update the `GET` portion to use `params`.

Comment: @Rainmaker I have made some updates to my answer based on the astute observations by sam_s. I wasn't quite right.

Comment: @AdrianLarson : I have updated my question. Can you tell me how to pass parameter value in workbench ?.

Comment: @Rainmaker Just add a `queryString` as you would with a page: `?sapId=someValue`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Tx...Now I am able to actually invoke the HTTPGet call using the following syntax  /services/apexrest/LeadSAP?sapId=00QN0000003ktzZMAQ